# sorting contents of a file

Tags: python, file, sorting, unix

In unix (specifically, I'm using `bash`), I can sort the contents of a file easily; given I have a file:

```
chris@chris:~$ cat testSort.txt 
3       1       test01
8       2       test02
6       3       test03
7       4       test04
1       5       test05
```

Running `sort` will return the sorted values based on the 1st column

```
chris@chris:~$ sort testSort.txt
1       5       test05
3       1       test01
6       3       test03
7       4       test04
8       2       test02
```

the results of which I can pipe into a file or a program as necessary; is there a way as easy as this in python, or do I need to read my file in, save it as a data structure of some sort, and then save it again?

**Confusion**

I'm not sure why I've received a downvote - I asked if there was a way as simple as in unix (i.e. a 1 word command) to achieve a sort.  I even provided an example to show what I wanted? In what way does this mean that "the question shows no research effort, it is unclear or not useful"?

Comment: How do you think `sort` does it?

Comment: Here's `sort` reimplemented in Python: `sys.stdout.writelines(sorted(sys.stdin))`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I have absolutely no idea how `sort` actually works

Comment: @ChrisW: Think about what is required to sort file contents. If the very last line would be sorted first, how would `sort` know this without having read the whole file into memory first?

Comment: @larsmans -- Be fair.  `sort` does a whole lot more than just a simple lexicographic sort if you want it to.  It can sort based on numeric input from a particular field in the file, etc, etc.  (All of which you can do in python of course), but it's not quite that simple.

Comment: @mgilson: true, but that one-liner is the gist of it. +1 to your answer, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How easily do you want to do it?  This sorts lexicographically, but you can modify it to sort based on any arbitrary criterion you have by passing an additional `key` function to `sorted`.

```
with open('input') as f:
    sorted_file = sorted(f)

#save to a file
with open('output') as f:
    f.writelines(sorted_file)

#write to stdout
import sys
sys.stdout.writelines(sorted_file)
```

Comment: Looks like there isn't a 1 line answer then! Back to reading Programming Python since I don't really understand this answer...

Comment: @ChrisW -- Do you mean `import sys; sys.stdout.writelines(sorted(open('input')))`?  That's 2 lines joined with a `;` -- But it's really not a good idea to write code that way.

Comment: I want it cross platform, so I know enough that that answer isn't a good idea.  I was impressed that it could be done with 1 word in unix, and was just wondering if this could be replicated in python - the answer obviously seems to be no! I'll go off to learn how to read files in since that seems to be the next stage...

Comment: @ChrisW -- That answer is cross platform.  It's just really hard to read and to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @mgilson well I understand even less than I thought I did!